# ltrim only numbers not letters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a function that will trim all the numbers from the start of a string, up to the letter it hits.

Not sure if I should be using regular expressions or !is_numeric or what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = ltrim($string, '0..9');
```

http://php.net/ltrim

Comment: +1. Shows once again that consulting the docs is helpful ;-) (I certainly didn't know that `ltrim` does that).

Answer (score -1):

you can use

$item = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $item);